# Synonym proposal for [oracledb] -> [node-oracledb]

Tags: support, synonym-request

The tag wiki for [oracledb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracledb) states:

> This tag is for node-oracledb, the Oracle Database driver for Node.js maintained by Oracle Corp.  Do not use this tag for questions *only* about Oracle database.

The tag wiki for [node-oracledb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/node-oracledb) states

> The [node-oracledb](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb) add-on for [node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/node.js) powers high performance Oracle Database applications.
>
> Use node-oracledb to connect Node.js 6, 8, 10 and 11 to [oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle) Database.

The tag descriptions are essentially the same with the  [oracledb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracledb) tag referring to [node-oracledb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/node-oracledb) but searching for one doesn't bring up results for the other.

They should be merged into [node-oracledb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/node-oracledb) (since it makes it explicitly clear that it is a node module rather than using just [oracledb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracledb) which can be easily confused for [oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle)).

Comment: Retagging will be required by the looks of it. Some oracledb tagged questions are actually oracle questions, others will be node-oracledb questions.

Comment: To be honest, this is very confusing. Who thought it is a good idea to use `oracledb` for a module in node.js and `oracle` as a tag for the oracle database. Wouldn't it make sense to cleanup `oracledb` and only use that for the database and make `oracle` a synonym of `oracledb`?

Comment: @Tom I would disagree with the final part as `Oracle` is the name of the RDBMS (not `OracleDB` - and we don't call them `MySQLDB` or `SQLServerDB`). But a clean-up of `[oracledb]` to the correct tags makes sense and once that's done there is an argument for making `[orabledb]` a synonym of either `[oracle]` or `[node-oracledb]` or just blacklisting it as being too confusing.

Comment: @MT0 No, the database is named "Oracle Database" (https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/), not just "Oracle" (although it is often simplified as just "Oracle", but we shouldn't do that in our tags). Oracle is the company name (actually it is Oracle Corp.). And of course we don't name it "MySQLDB", because the database is called MySQL. I would argue for removal of the `oracle` tag, because we don't need to tag a company.

Comment: @Tom This is going off the topic of the two tags I'd mentioned. If you want to suggest renaming `[oracle]` then it probably needs a separate thread so it can be properly discussed rather than hijacking this one.

Comment: Don't put tag references in code blocks. Use the `[tag:name]` syntax.

Answer (score 4):

[oracledb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracledb) should just be burned, not synonymized. Very few users are going to think it means a particular language's client library, as evidenced by numerous questions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58214053/1394393), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58149749/1394393), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57788082/1394393)) in the tag unrelated to Node. [Less than half](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracledb+node.js) the questions in it include [node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/node.js); while there might be some just missing the tag, a skim over [the questions without it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracledb+-node.js) suggests most have nothing to do with it.

So [oracledb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracledb) should just go because it's too easily confused in practice. If users are having trouble finding [node-oracledb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/node-oracledb), [oracledb-node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracledb-node) might be a suitable synonym.