# Rename [oracle] to [oracle-database]

Tags: discussion, status-review, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

As per [past discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253840/14998487) there should be no company tags. [oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle) still exists, but as per excerpt:

> Oracle Database is a Multi-Model Database Management System created by Oracle Corporation. Do NOT use this tag for other products owned by Oracle, such as Java and MySQL.

It is actually a product tag for [Oracle database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_Database). As of posting, no such tag exists. Therefore, [oracle-database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle-database) should be created. As per [this comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427425/isnt-teltonika-tag-a-company-advertising-too-much-for-it/427453#comment980442_427453), [oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle) should become a synonym for it.

---

Semi-related: There seem to have been [oracledb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracledb), but it was [burned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/390425/14998487) sometime after [discussing making it a synonym](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/390425/14998487) for [oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle). Regardless I would prefer [oracle-database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle-database) over [oracledb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracledb).

Comment: When a product's name is the same as the name of the company, I feel like it's ok to have such a tag.

Comment: @Dharman I'd advocate for a change anyway, as do-not-use-for in experts usually hints at the tag being at risk of misuse.

Comment: Same for tag  "apache" (discussed multiple times)

Comment: One potential misuse for the oracle tag is if a user is running their code on oracle's cloud

Comment: What questions are there in the tag that *aren't* about Oracle databases? (While I see some questions that are about Oracle Cloud, some of those seem to be about Oracle databases too.)

Comment: I said potential. I haven't personally seen any, but renaming the tag may prevent future misuse

Comment: @Laurel: Oracle "[owns](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html)" Java. Though the association hasn't really been observed in the wild.

Comment: @Fastnlight It would be confusing to rename the tag if there are questions that aren't about databases in it, so that should be taken care of first. (The rename itself also would also come at a cost: it will wipe out any tag badge history.)

Comment: Let us consult the [oracle].

Comment: The turn tables have turned. Let's decide the [oracle]'s fate

Comment: @Dharman Going through https://www.oracle.com, it looks like Oracle exclusively refers to the product as "Oracle Database".  Given the number of other "Oracle Xxx" products they have, I don't think "Oracle" is a unique product name at this point.

Comment: How many questions are using oracle to mean the company or another product from them? If we rename it, that will make those questions confusing.

Comment: FWIW, I believe the Oracle tag is pretty clean right now. I've personally looked at the title and tags for almost every [oracle] question for over a decade now. About a few times a month I change [oracle] to something like [oraclelinux], [java], [virtualbox], [mysql], [oracle-cloud-infrastructure], etc. In practice, the tag works fine right now. That's no guarantee about the future, but I don't plan on stopping my crusade for tag perfection any time soon.

Comment: @Laurel I (and several others) keep the Oracle tag pretty clean. I'll re-tag 99.9% of the off-topic questions in that tag to something more relevant and ensure that it is solely about the Oracle RDBMS and not about other Oracle products. (The ones I miss are when I'm on vacation or the very rare cases where there is a niche Oracle product that uses an Oracle database as a back-end but the question isn't quite about the database but there isn't a tag for that front-end product and I can't find something more relevant).

Comment: @MTO so you would approve of the change to lessen the workload?

Comment: 2+ years ago I would have argued to keep it as it is. The database's name is "Oracle" and the company's name is "Oracle Corporation" (which is shortened to Oracle); it is referred to as "Oracle Database" in the oracle.com documentation to disambiguate it from other Oracle Corporation products (the branding on oracle.com is very similar for many products so it is sometimes very difficult to tell what product you are looking at on their website). You do not see people asking to re-tag to [sql-server-database] or [postgresql-database].

Comment: These days, I don't care what you call the tag.

Comment: There is something to say for not touching a name that everyone knows. Oracle database engineers have been tagging their questions "oracle" for over a decade now.

Comment: As for reducing the workload - it won't do much. Most curation is when [oracle-sqldeveloper] should be [oracle] or [plsql] should be [sql] or sometimes [oracle] should be [oracle-cloud-infrastructure] or [oracle-apex] or [weblogic] or several other products but many of those later ones would still be mis-tagged they use an Oracle RDBMS in the background and people think they have to tag every tech. It is rare that [Oracle] is used as a company tag; that mainly occurs when people want to ask about Oracle's Java JDK (rather than OpenJDK) and I haven't seen that in the last month or two.

Comment: Is there any evidence the current tag naming is causing any actual problem?

Comment: @MartinSmith Not a huge amount that I have seen. The biggest historical problem was the [oracledb] tag and confusion between that and [oracle], [node-oracledb] and [oracledb-node] but that got retagged into the correct tags and [oracledb-node] was retagged to [node-oracledb]. Apart from that its just the common misconceptions of tagging the name of the client application when you should tag the database or that PL/SQL = SQL or that any question that looks sideways at a database should have the database tag added to it which won't be fixed by renaming the tag.

Comment: The main instance when [oracle] is used as a company name is when people have a question about Java and they specifically want the Oracle JDK rather than any JDK (or openJDK) and they think adding the [oracle] tag is the way to do it. However, that doesn't happen very often, we fix it when it does and mostly those questions are off-topic as they relate to where to download it or licensing.

Comment: The other ones are people tagging [oracle] + [cloud] or [oracle] + [apex] with they should use [oracle-cloud-infrastructure] or [oracle-apex].

Comment: It's not just about what we're used to, but about making the tag intuitive and accessible for all users, especially newcomers. Oracle has long moved on from being a purely database company.

Comment: @Gimby and? Users have been mistagging stuff since SO inception. They are already doing it.

Comment: I support having it changed also.

Comment: @Braiam spoken like a true council of meta member :)

Comment: I may have been premature with my `status-completed` - attempting to rename the tag has failed/timed out. I'll check back in a bit later to try again

Comment: @Rob want me to re-flag the question?

Comment: @A-Tech nope that's alright, I've already reraised a flag so we don't forget. I've pinged a CM and am waiting for a response

Comment: Where are all the questions? I don't agree with the change, whatever, but where are all the [oracle] questions? The new tag only has 5 vs the tens-of-thousands it held previously.

Comment: @thatjeffsmith see [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/427789/14998487)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

+1 [oracle-database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle-database) — I'm all for a less ambiguous tag that is unlikely to be misused on questions about other Oracle products.

Without reading the tag wiki, I would assume that [oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle) would be applicable to any product from Oracle the company and not just to their database product.  It seems that many users asking questions don't read the tag wiki either because questions about other Oracle products frequently get tagged with it.  It looks clean now only because a dedicated group of curators constantly monitor and re-tag questions.

[M Justin points out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427484/rename-oracle-to-oracle-database#comment980668_427484) that Oracle (the company) exclusively refers to its database product as "Oracle Database."

If you search for "oracle" on Google, databases are not prominent.  Google even suggests "oracle database" as a related search.

[image]

"Oracle" also has another meaning in theoretical computer science: a magic box that provides an answer, which helps with some algorithm proofs.

Comment: Ok, but what happened to all the questions previously tagged as [oracle], the new tag (synonym) only has 5 questions attached.

Comment: @thatjeffsmith  I see "150,930 questions" under [tag:oracle-database]  now.

Comment: I see 6 @stephen-ostermiller

Comment: also there's no guidance on the tag, that can't be copied over from the existing [oracle] tag?

Comment: I copied the [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/oracle-database/info) over using the Google cache version of it with a browser plugin that allows me to copy from a page to markdown.  I edited in the new tag name `oracle` -> `oracle-database` where appropriate.  I did NOT remove the guidance about misusing the tag for other Oracle products.  That is hopefully unnecessary new and SHOULD be removed.

Comment: Now I took care of that unnecessary usage guidance.  In the excerpt, I replaced it with the "When posting questions with the oracle tag, please be sure to always include Oracle edition and version." usage guidance.

Comment: I don't think the new tag has the code language for syntax highlighting set to  `lang-sql` like the old tag did.  I don't think I can change that, but maybe a moderator can.

Answer (score 5):

#### What is in a name?

The Oracle Corporation release "Oracle version 2" RDBMS in 1979 and the software was called "Oracle" not "Oracle Database".

As Oracle Corporation grew, it acquired more products and from "Oracle 8" it started referring to the RDBMS software as "Oracle Database" to disambiguate its other product lines but the RDBMS is still commonly referred to as "Oracle" rather than "Oracle Database".

This abbreviation is particularly noticeable as other RDBMS are referred to as "SQL Server", "MySQL", "Posgres" or "PostgreSQL" and not as "??? Database".

#### What is the actual problem?

There appear to be two problems that are attempting to be solved:

1. Don't use tags with the same name as a company.
2. Reduce the curation work.

If the only problem we are trying to solve is #1 then that should be applied to all tags across Stack Overflow.

If we are trying to solve #2 then we need to understand what the main curation issues with the [oracle-*] tags are are:

- Mis-tagging anything that is vaguely related to a database with the database tag even if the question is not actually about the database. That is probably the most common case when the [oracle] tag is applied and then removed. Renaming the tag is not going to solve that problem because people are deliberately using the database's tag because they think its relevant when it is not (and new users often feel that they need to use all 5 tags on questions).
- Mis-typing sub-tags. One of the most common is typing `oracle apex` into the tag list and getting the two tags [oracle] and [apex] when they should have typed `oracle-apex` (hyphen instead of space) and got a single tag. Similarly for `oracle cloud` instead of `oracle-cloud-infrastructure`. Renaming the tag may stop some of this but since Oracle Apex is built on top of Oracle RDBMS and people often tag both because the question is about using SQL queries through Oracle Apex's interface I really don't think that this will have a significant reduction on any curation efforts.
- Mis-tagging. This goes two ways:

  - The most common is using a related tag such as [oracle-sqldeveloper] because the user is interacting through the SQL Developer client and there is a commonly recurring misconception that "client application" = "database". Most of these questions are not specific to the client and actually should be tagged [oracle] because the question is about database functionality and not client functionality.
  - The less common is tagging [oracle] when the question is actually related to client functionality (usually around why does the code run in this client but not that client or why can I run individual statements and not a script). Again, renaming the tag is not going to solve these curation issues because the users believe that the problem is with the database and not with their client application (or that "client application" = "database").
- There is a very small minority of questions where the [oracle] tag is applied to relate to the company. This is typically when someone wants to ask specifically about Oracle's Java JDK and not about other JDK's. These can probably be counted on one hand over a year (the last one I curated was months ago) and they are almost always off-topic as the either want to know where to download it or about licensing and will swiftly get closed.

#### Should we change the tag name?

The main curation issues are not going to be solved by renaming the tag. It would have a minor positive effect but will likely not be hugely significant.

My personal opinion is that:

If it is easy to do then renaming the tag from [oracle] to [oracle-database] is not going break anything and may have a small positive benefit of disambiguating things; however, if it is going to take time from a moderator or a Stack Overflow employee that would be better spent on something more practical (or less cosmetic) then this should be (very) low priority.

Comment: The rename would take less than 5 minutes and can be done by a moderator. However, renaming it will cause all the "Oracle" tag badges to be deleted and new "Oracle-database" tag badges to be awarded all at once, losing the history (i.e., the date awarded will be the date of the rename) and [causing some confusion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/426570/6083675).

Answer (score 5):

I created the tag synonym for [oracle-database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle-database) (so no new questions can be tagged [oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle)) but the merge (rename) fails because there's 150k questions.

I'm tagging this [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) for a developer to complete the merge

Comment: For consistency, should we also rename the version specific tags? For example, should "oracle19c" change to "oracle-database19c"? Here are the relevant tags I could find:
oracle7
oracle8
oracle8i
oracle9i
oracle10g
oracle-xe
oracle-xe-18.4
oracle11g
oracle11gr1
oracle11gr2
oracle12c
oracle12.1
oracle12.2
oracle18c
oracle19c
oracle21c

Comment: Machavity, the suggestion from the developer is: merge the tags to get everything still with `oracle-database` on it get moved to `oracle`, then delete the synonym. After verifying that `oracle-database` doesn’t exist, perform a new tag “merge”  (under the hood it will be a rename)

Comment: @Berthold That's just it: it times out if you try. Have the developer try the mod merge tool. I never got it to work. It chokes somewhere around 10-15k questions.

Comment: @Machavity Understood, thanks for confirming that, I will follow up with them and report back.

Answer (score -3):

Lets do this. Only because this already happens with [oracle apex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle+apex), when Apex is another thing totally different. This will allow us to identify passively the misuse.

Answer (score -3):

You don't refer to the Oracle database as "Oracle Database", you call it "Oracle".

Analogously and as a counter-point, you don't think of any one tool from Microsoft as "Microsoft", you think of it in precise terms (Azure, Teams, TeamDynamix, etc).

Don't see a whole lot of value to creating this separate tag.

Comment: Renaming the 'oracle' tag to 'oracle-database' is about clarity and inclusivity, not creating a new tag. While 'oracle' is a well-understood shorthand among current users, Stack Overflow serves a diverse community. Precise tagging helps everyone.

Comment: @DavidS:  What about "Oracle" in a technical context is ambiguous?  Every professional context I've heard someone use it, it has always been about the database.  If they used a technology they'd prefix it with that.  If they were talking about the company they'd either contextualize it with "work for" or "yacht".

Comment: @Makoto I'D argue that there is some bias in that because you already work with that you think of oracle oracle-database. But someone using different oracle products or is just starting out is more likely to confuse it. E.g. I personally, I didn't think of the database when first encountering the tag.

Comment: This would be my line of thinking. It would be very warped if a bunch of people hanging around on MSO get to decide what happens to a high frequency tag such as "oracle"; let the people who have made their nest under that tag decide what is right and wrong with it. It's worked just fine thus far, so let's not do the meta thing and invent problems where there are none.

Comment: I work with Oracle DB daily, and I _definitely_ explicitly say Oracle DB to my coworkers, I never just say Oracle personally.  We do also use other Oracle products like Oracle Linux though.

Comment: @Makoto I don't usually work with the Oracle database, so when I'm talking about Oracle professionally, it's usually in the context of the company that currently owns Java.